# Raw SQL update statement while date value is set to NULL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have an SQL statement:

`UPDATE user SET name=?, email=?, password=?, gender=?, birthDate=? WHERE token=? AND email=? AND password = ?`

Everything works well but, when I try to set birthDate to NULL, I receive a SQLException.

The statement is correct (I checked it in phpMyAdmin console).

Setting birthDate to NULL:

```
        if (user.getBirthDate() != null)
            ps.setDate(5, user.getBirthDate());
        else
            ps.setNull(5, java.sql.Types.DATE);
```

When setting to random date (for example, Today) - everything works fine.

What is wrong with it? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have your column NOT NULL?\

Comment: Yes, it has NOT NULL column, but there is a trigger, which filters values and sets to the old ones. From BEFORE UPDATE trigger:

IF NEW.birthDate IS NULL THEN 
SET NEW.birthDate = OLD.birthDate;
END IF;

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some conditional logic in your java code to determine what your sql query will be.  If you want the birth date set to null, your statement has to be

```
UPDATE user SET name=?, email=?, password=?, gender=?, birthDate=null 
WHERE token=? AND email=? AND password = ?
```

Otherwise, as you've noticed, the query is fine.

Comment: BirthDate is an input optional param, if it is set to null, then I invoke setNull method, else I set value. MySQL trigger checks is it null, if yes - then sets old value, else - new.